# Set up latexmk for pdflatex in texlive

Tags: texlive, windows, latexmk

How do I set up for latexmk compilation for pdflatex in texlive? I have the following (see picture) setup for latexmk compilation for xelatex (I just found it somewhere), but I don't know what to change for pdflatex.

[image]

Comment: I'd guess the `xelatex` that follows `q/` should be `pdflatex`.  But I haven't used Windows in almost a decade.

Comment: Latexmk should use pdfLaTeX by default with the `-pdf` switch: did you try just removing the `$pdflatex ...` line?

Comment: @JosephWright That seems to work, although I see a warning I have never seen before: ``Unquoted string "tex" may clash with future reserved word at (eval 8) line 2`` (possibly completely unrelated).

Comment: `latexmk` is a Perl script. You must have a Perl interpreter installed in your machine.

Comment: @RaniereSilva Yes ...? I don't understand what you are trying to tell me ...

Comment: Some time ago I try to use `latexmk` in a W* machine with MiKTeX and have no success because the machine haven't a Perl script. AFAIK the LaTeX distribution don't install a Perl script. I just want to warning you about this.

Comment: As seen in my question, I use texlive (in Windows). Texlive comes with its own perl interpreter.

Comment: @JosephWright I think your suggestion doesn't quite work. When compiling the tex file I just posted in http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/132660/count-items-later-in-the-document, I get (in addition to the ``Unquoted string "tex" ...`` warning, a ``fontspec`` error ``The fontspec package requires either XeTeX or LuaTeX to function``.

Comment: @Sverre Well you can't use `fontspec` with pdfLaTeX, so that is not really a surprise. You _have_ to use either XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX to use `fontspec`.

Comment: @JosephWright I know, but if you look at the linked document, I'm not loading ``fontspec``, so I'm baffled.

Comment: @Sverre OK, drop the `-e` (it seems this is actually linked to the `xelatex` business). For me, that removes the warning, and `latexmk -pdf <filename>` with the linked demo is fine.

Comment: Good. If you don't mind, I'll provide a quick and simple answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on Joseph's comments, this:

[image]

---

The latexmk procedure for `xelatex` given in the question can also be simplified to the following:

[image]

Comment: Along the lines of this configuration, you should be able to simplify the `xelatex` configuration: Just replace `-pdf` (from this configuration) with `-xelatex`. The only difference seems to be that the configuration you posted heeds some variable `$synctexoption`, which I can’t find in the latexmk documentation, so I’m guessing it’s TeXworks-specific. What happens if you keep the `xelatex` configuration and only replace `xelatex` (in the 3rd line) with `pdflatex`?

Comment: @doncherry You seem to be suggesting two different things here. I tried your first suggestion, and that seemed to work fine in the document I tested it on. I'll add it to my answer above.

Comment: Yes, those were two different things. Overall, there should be (at least) four possible configurations, two each for `pdflatex` and `xelatex`. The one not pictured yet is the `pdflatex` configuration I described in the second part of my last comment.

Comment: Since the one I pictured would be the simpler one, I guess that should be preferable.