# Count items later in the document

Tags: cross-referencing, counters

The question is simple enough: How can I make the following output of my counter (`\themycounter`) say `6`?

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcounter{mycounter}
\newcommand{\myitem}{\refstepcounter{mycounter}}
\begin{document}
I have some reason to tally up some items here\myitem \myitem \myitem.
But how many items are there in total in this document?
Are there {\themycounter} items?
Surely there are more since I am tallying up some more items now\myitem \myitem \myitem.
\end{document}
```

I'm quite confident that the answer doesn't need to be as complicated as the one given in [Displaying a later value of a counter](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39356/displaying-a-later-value-of-a-counter) (which is why I'm taking the liberty to ask here).

Comment: Well, it's Gonzalo who's actually _showing_ how to use the ``totcount`` package, so this thread is definitely to prefer over the original.

Comment: I reference two answerd, but can only pick one as a possible duplicate source. The [latter one](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/34789/5764) shows exactly what is needed.

Comment: Oh, you're right. Well, both Gonzalo and jfbu provided excellent answers below (don't know how I can choose one over the other). Feel free to close as duplicate (but I hope the question will remain here, since Gonzalo's and jfbu's answers are easier for novice users like me to follow).

Comment: Since the question is active and has answers, it will remain if found by others so no worries. You can even accept an answer as usual (Gonzalo's is more general and doesn't require a `\label`, which has to be placed after the last `\myitem` for it to work). Even *you* could cast a vote-to-close if you feel that one of the mentioned posts are duplicates.

Comment: Good. I see now that egreg's answer doesn't show how to step up the counter (granted, I know how to do that, but since Gonzalo's answer includes that too, it's better). I prefer MWE answers :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [`totcount`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/totcount) package; you create and register the counter with `\newtotcounter{<counter>}` and then use `\total{<counter>}` (needs two or three runs):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{totcount}
\newtotcounter{mycounter}
\newcommand{\myitem}{\refstepcounter{mycounter}}

\begin{document}
I have some reason to tally up some items here\myitem \myitem \myitem.
But how many items are there in total in this document?
Are there {\themycounter} items? No, there are \total{mycounter}, since I am tallying up some more items now\myitem \myitem \myitem.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I took the liberty to simplify your code with the single command ``\newtotcounter``, which both creates and registers the counter.

Comment: @Sverre no problem. Edits to improve code are always welcome. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Following `egreg` answer to the [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39356/displaying-a-later-value-of-a-counter) you linked too: (see also better variant next)

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcounter{mycounter}
\newcommand{\myitem}{\refstepcounter{mycounter}}
\begin{document}
I have some reason to tally up some items here\myitem \myitem \myitem.
But how many items are there in total in this document?
Are there \ref{finalmyitem} items?
Surely there are more since I am tallying up some more items now\myitem \myitem \myitem\label{finalmyitem}.
\end{document}
```

This method (originating in the comments) avoids having to add manually a  `\label` after the last `\myitem`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcounter{mycounter}

%%   \newcommand{\myitem}{\refstepcounter{mycounter}}
%% \AtEndDocument{\addtocounter{mycounter}{-1}\myitem\label{finalmyitem}}

% again a variant:
\newcommand{\myitem}{\stepcounter{mycounter}}
\AtEndDocument{\addtocounter{mycounter}{-1}\refstepcounter{mycounter}\label{finalmyitem}}

\begin{document}
I have some reason to tally up some items here\myitem \myitem \myitem.
But how many items are there in total in this document?
Are there {\ref{finalmyitem}} items?
Surely there are more since I am tallying up some more items now\myitem \myitem \myitem.
\end{document}
```

[image: 6 items]

Comment: I am assuming you want a `6` to be printed, not a `3`, and the this is what the code proposed here does.

Comment: I didn't understand egreg's original answer. Thanks for providing a much simplified version! :)

Comment: Perhaps one can even do `\AtEndDocument{\label{finalmyitem}}` so there's no need to manually place the label.

Comment: @jfbu Ah, yes, you're right. Disregard my comments; in fact, I'll delete them shortly.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina  however one could do `\AtEndDocument{\myitem\label{finalmyitem}}` and arrange to manually decrease by one when referencing. (untested, to be implmented)

Comment: @jfbu That sounds better, but an `\myitem` in a delayed float caption, for example, might still cause problems.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina would my updated answer have this problem with a delayed float caption?

Comment: @jfbu I don't know for sure. I am not sure exactly at what point delayed floats are processed. Perhaps someone else can answer this (Werner, if I recall correctly, once needed something like that, so he or egreg, or David)

Comment: @GonzaloMedina: Look at the [`atveryend` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/atveryend) for this.