Automatically summing up of points in a protocol
I'm working on a LaTeX document where I keep a detailed protocol of various meditation sessions, including the points I earn for each session. The document is organized by different hierarchical sections (H0, H1, H2, etc.), and each section contains multiple dated entries. I need help automating the summation of these points in two specific contexts within the document.
Description of the Document Structure:
Front Page:
On the front page of my document, I summarize the total points I've accumulated across different sections (e.g., H0, H1, H2, etc.).
For example:
Total Points Applied For: 1 (H0) + 11 (H1) + 11 (H2) = 23
Here, "H0," "H1," and "H2" are different sections or protocol segments within the document, and the numbers represent the total points for that section.
Section-Specific Summation:
Each section (e.g., H1, H2) should sum the points only within that section, excluding points from other sections.
The sum should appear on the front page in the format shown above (i.e., Total Points Applied For: 1 (H0) + 11 (H1) + 11 (H2) = 23).
I would like the date to automatically show the total points for that day as "29.10.2024 (9 Points)" where the 9 is the sum of the points from the individual entries.
Here is the version of the code I’m currently using for the document:

\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{pagecolor}
\definecolor{lightblue}{RGB}{173, 216, 230}

% ---------------------------------------
% Macro for new protocol page
% ---------------------------------------
\newcommand*\sepstars{%
  \begin{center}
    $\star\star\star$
  \end{center}
  \newpage
}

% ---------------------------------------
% Macro for additional light blue page
% ---------------------------------------
\newcommand{\addLightBluePage}{
  \newpage
  \pagecolor{lightblue}
  \color{black}
}

% ---------------------------------------
% Macro for Meditation Entry
% ---------------------------------------
\newcommand{\meditationEntry}[8]{
    \ifnum#1=1
    \else\ifnum#1=2
        \paragraph{Meditation Entry (#8 Points)}
    \else
        \paragraph{Invalid Argument: #1. Please use 1 for a single entry or 2 for multiple entries.}
    \fi\fi
    \begin{itemize}[label={}]
        \item \textbf{Category:} #2
        \item \textbf{Name:} #3
        \item \textbf{Time:} #4
        \item \textbf{Duration:} #5 minutes
        \item \textbf{Setting:} #6
        \item \textbf{Incidents:} #7
    \end{itemize}
    \smallskip
}

% ---------------------------------------
% Macro for Joker Meditation Entry
% ---------------------------------------
\newcommand{\jokerMeditation}[7]{
    \ifnum#1=1
        \paragraph{Meditation Entry}
    \else\ifnum#1=2
        \paragraph{Meditation Entry (#7 Points)}
    \else
        \paragraph{Invalid Argument: #1. Please use 1 for a single entry or 2 for multiple entries.}
    \fi\fi
    \begin{itemize}[label={}]
        \item \textbf{Category:} #2
        \item \textbf{Name:} #3
        \item \textbf{Description:} #4
        \item \textbf{Setting:} #5
        \item \textbf{Incidents:} #6
    \end{itemize}
    \smallskip
}

% ---------------------------------------
% Macro for Attended Meditation Entry
% ---------------------------------------
\newcommand{\attendedMeditation}[8]{
    \ifnum#1=1
    \else\ifnum#1=2
        \paragraph{Attended Meditation Entry (#8 Points)}
    \else
        \paragraph{Invalid Argument: #1. Please use 1 for a single entry or 2 for multiple entries.}
    \fi\fi
    \begin{itemize}[label={}]
        \item \textbf{Category:} Attended Meditation
        \item \textbf{Name:} #2
        \item \textbf{TUWEL ID:} #3
        \item \textbf{Time:} #4
        \item \textbf{Duration:} #5 minutes
        \item \textbf{Setting:} #6
        \item \textbf{Incidents:} #7
    \end{itemize}
    \smallskip
}

% ---------------------------------------
% Macro for Self-Study
% ---------------------------------------
\newcommand{\selfStudy}[2]{
\paragraph{Self-study data}
    \begin{itemize}[label={}]
        \item {Rating:} #1
        \item #2
    \end{itemize}
    \medskip
}

% ---------------------------------------
% Macro for the front page format
% ---------------------------------------
\newcommand{\frontPage}[1]{
    \begin{center}
        {\huge \textbf{#1}} \\[1.5cm]
        Max Mustermann \\[0.3cm]
        12345678 \\[0.3cm]
        e-mail address \\[1cm]
        \textbf{Last changed:} DD.MM.YYYY \\[0.3cm]
        \textbf{Number of Pages of the Current Series:} 21 \\[0.3cm]
        \textbf{Total Points Applied For:} 1 (H0) + 51 (#1) = 52 \\[0.5cm]
    \end{center}
    \paragraph{Questions:}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item Your Question 1?
        \item Your Question 2?
    \end{itemize}
    \paragraph{My Buddy:} Maria Musterfrau (87654321) \\
    \textbf{Last contact:} DD.MM.YYYY
    \paragraph{Special achievements:}
        \begin{itemize}
        \item Your Achievement 1 
        \item Your Achievement 2
        \end{itemize}

    \vspace*{0.5cm}
    \begin{center}
        \begin{tabular}{@{}p{.5in}p{4in}@{}}
            Signature: & \hrulefill , \today{} \\
        \end{tabular}
    \end{center}

    \vspace*{0.5cm}
    
    \paragraph{Self-Study Overview}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item Self Study Summary: Your text...
        \item Self Study Question: Your question
        \item Next Self Study Question: Your next question
        \item (optional) Rating Scale: 1-5 (1 = Poor, 5 = Excellent)
    \end{itemize}

    \paragraph{Written Notices:}
        \begin{enumerate}
                \item Missed meeting on DD/MM/YYY \\
                \textit{Add reason and signature of someone to approve your missing (ideally image of written notice of doctor, but can also be signature of the buddy)}
                \item Missed meeting on DD/MM/YYY \\
                \textit{Add reason and signature of someone to approve your missing (ideally image of written notice of doctor, but can also be signature of the buddy)}
        \end{enumerate}

    % Add a light blue page if content overflows
    \ifdim\pagetotal>18cm
        \addLightBluePage
    \fi
}

% ---------------------------------------
% FRONT PAGE OF THE PROTOCOL H4
% ---------------------------------------

\begin{document}
\pagecolor{lightblue}
\frontPage{H4}
\addLightBluePage{}

\newpage
\pagecolor{white}

% ---------------------------------------
% Example Entry after H4
% ---------------------------------------

\section*{29.10.2024 (9 Points)}

\jokerMeditation{2}{Full joker meditation}{Name of the meditation}{your description}{alone}{none}{2}
\meditationEntry{2}{Full Meditation}{Kundalini}{20:30-21:30}{60}{alone}{It was very loud outside.}{2}
\attendedMeditation{2}{Name of the meditation}{12345}{8:30-9:30}{60}{group}{none}{5}
\selfStudy{5}{Your self study text...}

% ---------------------------------------
% FRONT PAGE OF THE PROTOCOL H3
% ---------------------------------------
\addLightBluePage{}
\frontPage{H3}
\addLightBluePage{}

\newpage
\pagecolor{white}

% ---------------------------------------
% Example Entry after H3
% ---------------------------------------

\section*{30.10.2024 (8 Points)}

\meditationEntry{1}{Short Meditation}{Breath Awareness}{07:00-08:00}{60}{alone}{calm and peaceful}{4}
\selfStudy{4}{Your self study text...}

% ---------------------------------------
% FRONT PAGE OF THE PROTOCOL H2
% ---------------------------------------
\addLightBluePage{}
\frontPage{H2}
\addLightBluePage{}

\newpage
\pagecolor{white}

% ---------------------------------------
% Example Entry after H2
% ---------------------------------------

\section*{31.10.2024 (7 Points)}

\jokerMeditation{2}{Short joker meditation}{Name of the meditation}{short description}{alone}{none}{3}
\selfStudy{3}{Your self study text...}

% ---------------------------------------
% FRONT PAGE OF THE PROTOCOL H1
% ---------------------------------------
\addLightBluePage{}
\frontPage{H1}
\addLightBluePage{}

\newpage
\pagecolor{white}

% ---------------------------------------
% Example Entry after H1
% ---------------------------------------

\section*{01.11.2024 (10 Points)}

\attendedMeditation{2}{Guided Meditation}{67890}{10:00-11:00}{60}{group}{none}{6}
\selfStudy{4}{Your self study text...}

\end{document}

What I Need Help With:
Automatic Summation on the Front Page:
I need a way to automatically calculate and display the total points for each section (H0, H1, H2, etc.) and then sum them to produce a final total on the front page. The format should be something like:
Total Points Applied For: 1 (H0) + 11 (H1) + 11 (H2) = 23
The points displayed for each section (e.g., H1, H2) should only reflect the points earned within that section and not include points from other sections.
Only the highest points of one day should be used, or the student should be able to write 0 to all but one entries each day.
I would appreciate any guidance or examples of how to implement this in LaTeX, whether through counters, custom macros, or any other method.
Thank you in advance for your help!
See also this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78918329/automatically-summing-up-of-points-in-a-protocol

https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34789/how-to-display-the-final-value-of-a-counter-at-the-beginning-of-a-document seems relevant as well.

With https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/132660/count-items-later-in-the-document?noredirect=1&lq=1 providing an MWE for the totcount approach.

Thank you for all your comments. I checked the linked questions that you suggested but my question really differs from previous ones...

Can you please explain, best via editing your question, what’s the difference? The links deal with counting, i.e. adding.

Please add the code in the question here, instead of using an Overleaf link. Externally linked code might change or be deleted, making the question much less useful for future visitors. Simplify the code as much as possible while making sure it is still complete and compilable.

I added the whole code here!

Are you still interested in a response? The easiest is to replace \section*{01.11.2024 (10 Points)} mark-up by  \mysection{01.11.2024}{10} which will both resolve to using \section and store suitable data into the .aux file.  This data defines "storage" macros where the dates and numbers can be put. Doing the arithmetic is immediate using \numexpr for which LaTeX3 has a slim layer called \inteval which looks more like a normal LaTeX command (but is internally almost nothing more than \the\numexpr..\relax).
